# How to call a javascript from master page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, master-pages, alerts

I'm trying to call a javascript alert from a master page, where i got an update panel. Within that a button and a text box.

I need to call the alert on clicking the button in my master page. So far it seems not working. Please help.

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
                        (this.GetType(), "alert", "invokeMeMaster();", true);
```

This is what i wrote in my button click. invokerMEMaster include just an alert message.I need to reload the page on the ok button click of the alert. How can i do that as well?

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Update Panel clears javascript code when Postback so try to put this code on the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
function(){

   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler); 
   function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {//put your code here}

});

</script>
```

Comment: i need to add alert messages from code behind...How am i supposed to call my script if im using this in the source page?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx), with the ScriptManager residing in your content page

Answer (score 0):

If I may guess your problem (psychic debugging): When the update panel updates the javascript is not rendered of fired on your page.

Try to register your javascript like in the update panel:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page,typeof(string),"JavaScriptCall",script.ToString(), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you have a JS function in a content page that needs to be called from the master page?

What I would do is add a hidden input control and an alert function to your master page:

```
    <input runat="server" id="hdnAlert" name="Alert" type="hidden" />

    <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">  
        function AlertMe(){ alert(document.getElementByID("hdnAlert").value); }
    </script>
```

You could then change the value of the input control from a content page:

```
    HtmlInputHidden hdnTemp = new HtmlInputHidden();
    hdnTemp = (HtmlInputHidden)Master.FindControl("hdnAlert");
    hdnTemp.Value = "Message To Alert";
```

Then just have the button in your master page call the "AlertMe" function located in the master page.