# run javascript function from master page button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function on the child page that I need to run when the save button on the master page is clicked.

```
ValidateCheckList = function() {
        var ErrorCodeU1001 = "U1001";
        var ErrorCodeU1002 = "U1002";
        var ErrorCodeU1003 = "U1003";

        var errors = [];
        $('<%= errorsHiddenField.ClientID %>').val("0");

        var fingerprintsTaken = $('<%= FingerprintsTakenYesNo.PluginSelector %>').YesNoPlugin(YesNoMethodsEnum.IsYes);
        if (!fingerprintsTaken) {
            errors.push(ErrorCodeU1001);
        }

        var dnaTaken = $('<%= DNATakenYesNo.PluginSelector %>').YesNoPlugin(YesNoMethodsEnum.IsYes);
        if (!dnaTaken) {
            errors.push(ErrorCodeU1002);
        }

        var photographTaken = $('<%= PhotographTakenYesNo.PluginSelector %>').YesNoPlugin(YesNoMethodsEnum.IsYes);
        if (!photographTaken) {
            errors.push(ErrorCodeU1003);
        }

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            ('<%= errorsHiddenField.ClientID %>').val(errors.length.toString());
            $(document).PageUtilPlugin(PageUtilMethodsEnum.DisplayUserNotificationMessage, { messageType: "Warning", message: errors });
        }
    }
```

I have tried -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SaveButton").onclick = ValidateCheckList;
```

but this doesn't work.

It also needs to do a postback.

Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add the attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your `SaveButton` and the access it with jQuery instead of `document.getElementById`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760235/how-to-call-a-javascript-from-master-page

Answer (score 0):

try this 
change you code like this

```
function ValidateCheckList ()
{
  if(allvalidates)
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
}
```

on master page save button in page load

```
button.Attribute.Add("OnClick", "return ValidateCheckList ()");
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with the parent and child exactly ?
if you mean the pop-ed up window is the child window you can use this

```
childwindow = window.open("child.html", "Pop", "width=700,height=400, scrollbars=1");
childwindow.yourfunction();
```